# How to track down cause of ConnectionRefusedError for GPS device connected with the gpsd python library

Tags: python, gps, serial-port, windows-10, gpsd

I'll be brief:  I have a u-blox M8 GNSS evaluation kit, and I'm trying to pull location data from it as a sub-routine in a larger program.  But I'm being stumped at the outset.  My program terminates while trying to establish the initial connection with the following error:

```
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

I thought maybe another process was listening on the default port for gpsd (2947), but after calling 'netstat -a -n' (in windows command prompt) I was able to confirm that no other processes were blocking the port.  I don't know how to further pursue what the causes could be, and would be eager for any suggestions more experienced users might have.

**Edited to add more context for the lazy**
The program breaks off during the connect call (literally the first line of my own program), which you can see below for context:

```
def connect(host="127.0.0.1", port=2947):
""" Connect to a GPSD instance
:param host: hostname for the GPSD server
:param port: port for the GPSD server
"""
global gpsd_socket, gpsd_stream, verbose_output, state
logger.debug("Connecting to gpsd socket at {}:{}".format(host, port))
gpsd_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
gpsd_socket.connect((host, port))
gpsd_stream = gpsd_socket.makefile(mode="rw")
logger.debug("Waiting for welcome message")
welcome_raw = gpsd_stream.readline()
welcome = json.loads(welcome_raw)
if welcome['class'] != "VERSION":
    raise Exception(
        "Unexpected data received as welcome. Is the server a gpsd 3 server?")
logger.debug("Enabling gps")
gpsd_stream.write('?WATCH={"enable":true}\n')
gpsd_stream.flush()

for i in range(0, 2):
    raw = gpsd_stream.readline()
    parsed = json.loads(raw)
    _parse_state_packet(parsed)
```

Comment: Do you have GPSD installed on your system? sudo apt-get install gpsd